# Определение размера изображения в npy

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, numpy, ос

Функция output изображений:

```
img_info = Image.open(os.path.join(mask_test_path, '0'+img_f))
(image_cols, image_rows) = img_info.size
...
imgs =      np.ndarray((total, image_rows, image_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
...
img       = imread(img_adress, img_name), as_gray=make_gray) #make_gray - меняется в настройках
imgs[0] = img 
np.save(os.path.join(npy_adress, 'imgs_test.npy'), imgs)
```

Здесь все норм...

А теперь

Функция input изображений:

```
imgs_train       = np.load(os.path.join(npy_data_path, 'imgs_train.npy')
***
imgs_p = np.ndarray((imgs.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Как видим, для np.ndarray нужно знать размеры изображения. Здесь-то у меня и ступор. Поможете?

Спасибо!

Comment: В PIL есть функция размер изображения

Comment: @Александр, я именно ей и воспользовался в output функции, но данная функция, как я понял, неприменима к imread в input

Comment: Рядом создал тему, в которой пытаюсь избавиться от ресайза, хочу посмотреть все случаи и выбрать наилучший

Comment: Здесь же будет с ресайзом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

здесь вы читаете с диска массив данных Numpy - скорее всего это сохраненные картинки в виде 3D (градации серого) или 4D (RGB) Numpy NDArray:

```
imgs_train = np.load(os.path.join(npy_data_path, 'imgs_train.npy')
```

после чтения массива с диска все размеры (измерения) уже известны - пример:

эмулируем Numpy массив, состоящий из 10 картинок (градации серого) размерности 200 x 200 и сохраняем его в файл:

```
In [88]: imgs = np.random.randint(255, size=(10,200,200))

In [89]: imgs.shape
Out[89]: (10, 200, 200)

In [90]: np.save(r'c:/temp/images.npy', imgs)
```

читаем массив из файла в новую переменную:

```
In [91]: new = np.load(r'c:/temp/images.npy')
```

размерность прочитанного массива:

```
In [92]: new.shape
Out[92]: (10, 200, 200)
```

---

непонятно что (и для чего) вы пытаетесь сделать в следующей строке:

```
imgs_p = np.ndarray((imgs.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols), dtype=np.uint8)
```

если у вас уже есть `.npy` файл, то его можно просто прочитать в переменную получив такой же Numpy NDArray, который был использован при записи

Comment: Cпасибо, не знал, что так можно